# Teaching in Canada

Tags: immigration, canada, employment, foreign-employment

Asking for a friend. She is working in India as a teacher. She has qualification (Bachelor of Education) and Masters (MA History). She intends to immigrate to canada.

What is the qualification of teachers for canada? Is Indian degree enough for that, or should she do additional education in canada? How can she find teaching jobs over there?

Regarding province, its not clear. Still in early stages of application.

Comment: Have you tried researching https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/work-canada/permit/temporary/need-work-permit-work.html?

Comment: @Traveller I have seen the link. This is not about work permit. Assuming she has PR, then what next is the question.

Comment: That’s not how I interpreted your question. You should edit it to clarify exactly what you mean

Comment: @Traveller I thought the question was clear. It's about requirements for becoming a teacher not about the immigration process itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am assuming that she wants to qualify to teach K-12 (elementary/secondary). If she wants to teach post-secondary, that will have different requirements. I notice her MA is in history. If she wants a qualification to teach history in Canada, she *might* need to take a course in Canadian or provincial history.

She will have to apply for certification in whichever province she settles in. She should do an internet search similar to "ontario canada foreign teacher credential" for the details.

Here's the [India page on country-specific information for foreign credentials](https://www.oct.ca/becoming-a-teacher/internationally-educated-teachers/country-info/country-i/country-india) for the province of Ontario. And here's a page for [Nova Scotia](https://certification.ednet.ns.ca/internationally-educated-teachers).

She'll need to have a Canadian background check, her mark sheets, letters attesting to her degrees and work, and so on. The Ontario page will be a good guideline even for other provinces because it describes how to interpret the Ontario College of Teachers (OCT) requirements for Indian practices and standards.

Note: questions on Stackexchange should focus on a single topic so I'm ignoring the question about how to find a job.